# Unable to read large file (8GB) using spring batch

Tags: java, out-of-memory, spring-batch, filereader, partitioning

I have 60 million records in a single CSV of size of about 8 GB.

Need to read records from file and insert it into database using JPA.

Trying to read this file with spring batch but performance is very slow. Rows I have added chunk size max to 1500 but didn't work.

also added task executor creating threads but did not work.

System config.
t2. xlarge 16 GiB of memory and 4 vCPU and 16GB RAM and 4 core cpu

```
 @Bean
public Step step3() {
    return stepBuilder
            .get("step3")
            .<main_Data, main_Data>chunk(1500)
            .reader(this.mainDataReader)
            .processor(this.main_data_processor)
            .writer(this.mainDataWriter).taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}



@Bean
public  TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(5);
    return  simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
}
```

also try with

```
  @Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor2() {
   ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
   executor.setCorePoolSize(64);
   executor.setMaxPoolSize(64);
   executor.setQueueCapacity(64);
   executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
   executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MultiThreaded-");
    return executor;
}
```

I also tried with OpenCsv but getting duplicate records using Opencsv.

Any suggestion on Spring batch performance or other way to read this file ?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to read the whole file into the memory? If your purpose is to either save each record to the database or reformat the records and write them to another file, you can make this operations line-by-line.

Comment: Not sure what your goal is here. Do you want to process the data from the CSV file? If so, maybe do that in the threads as well. If you just load it into memory it will remain slow no matter how many threads or CPU cores you throw at it, 8GB is a lot of data to put into memory.

Comment: @Jakub Biernaczyk No need read whole file into memory. Can read in chunks and need to insert to DB. He managed to read in chunks but facing time/slowness issue.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning

Comment: `performance is very slow`: do you have some numbers? What is slow according to you? `Rows I have added chunk size max to 1500 but didn't work.`: what, specifically, didn't work? Have you tried partitioning your file?